# verifying two mirrored directory trees

Tags: mirroring

Is there an easy way to verify that two directory trees on two separate machines are identical, and that all files within the directory tree are also identical? I want to make sure that two separate machines mirror the exact same data.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using linux, you can use rsync to accomplish this.  If you only want to check, from the source machine, you can do something like:

`rsync -av --dry-run /source/path dstcomputer:/dest/path`

The --dry-run will not actually change any data, only report.  You can re-run without that option to actually sync the data.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows, you can use [`robocopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx) to accomplish this (not included by default before Vista, but you can [get the Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) for XP). If you only want to check, from the source machine, you can do something like:

```
robocopy /source/path /dest/path /MIR /L
```

The /L will not actually change any data, only report. You can re-run without that option to actually sync the data.